# cURL to python Requests: form with file attachment

Tags: python, python-2.7, curl, python-requests

I have the following cURL request which works successfully:

```
curl https://daDomain.com/v2-beta/media \
 --header "Authorization: Bearer TOKEN" \
 --form media=@recording.mp3 \
 --form 'configuration={"configuration":{"keywords":{"groups":["data"]}}}'
```

Below is the python-requests version of the code, which when called returns a 400 error saying a "mediaUrl is not a valid URL".

```
import requests

headers = {}
headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer TOKEN"

url = "https://daDomain.com/v2-beta/media"
configuration = '{"configuration":{"keywords":{"groups":["data"]}}}'

filepath = 'recording.mp3'
files = {'media' : open('filepath.mp3', 'rb'), 'configuration' : configuration}

r = requests.post(url, headers = headers, files=files)
```